# Using JS to apply CSS when clicking buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a modal that when clicked it should popup full screen.
Everything is good, modal pops full screen but the header ( logo + menu ) still shows up.

I'm trying to use JS, so when the modal is clicked i want to apply a z-index to the header and when the close button is clicked i will apply another z-index to fix the header.

the link to be clicked is this:

```
<a class="vPlay vPlay-btn clickformodal" href="#modal-our-work-1" data-toggle="modal" data-video="241737557"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/play1.png" /></a>
```

Now  the JS code is this:

```
let open = document.selectElementByClassName("clickformodal");
let header = document.selectElementByClassName("mk-header");
let close = document.selectElementByClassName("close");


open.addEventListener('click', function () {
  header.classList.add("headerbefore");
});

close.addEventListener('click', function () {
  header.classList.remove("headerafter");
});
```

And this is the css that will be applied:

```
.headerbefore {
   z-index: 1;
 }

.headerafter {
   z-index: 301;
}
```

The issue here appart that it's not doing what it is supposed too, google chrome shows an error in console saying that `let open = document.selectElementByClassName("clickformodal");` is not a function.

What am i doing wrong here?

Help me out please, it's been 2 days that i'm trying to fix this and nothing till now :/

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things going wrong here:

1. it should be `getElementsByClassName`, not `selectElementByClassName`
2. as `getElementsByClassName` returns an element collection, you need to add `[0]` at its end, e.g. `document.getElementsByClassName("clickformodal")[0]`

---

```
let open = document.getElementsByClassName("clickformodal")[0];
let header = document.getElementsByClassName("mk-header")[0];
let close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


open.addEventListener('click', function () {
  header.classList.add("headerbefore");
});

close.addEventListener('click', function () {
  header.classList.remove("headerafter");
});
```

---

An option could be to use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead

```
let open = document.querySelector(".clickformodal");
let header = document.querySelector(".mk-header");
let close = document.querySelector(".close");


open.addEventListener('click', function () {
  header.classList.add("headerbefore");
});

close.addEventListener('click', function () {
  header.classList.remove("headerafter");
});
```

---

If to add to more than 1, use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (this sample assume there is as many *open* as *close* but only 1 *header*)

```
let open = document.querySelectorAll(".clickformodal");
let header = document.querySelector(".mk-header");
let close = document.querySelectorAll(".close");


for (var i = 0; i < open.length; i++) {    
   open[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
       header.classList.add("headerbefore");
   });
}

for (var j=0; j < close.length; j++) {
   close[j].addEventListener('click', function () {
       header.classList.remove("headerbefore");
   });
}
```

Comment: @xake Maybe you should do `remove("headerbefore");` instead of `remove("headerafter");`

Comment: u are the man! Thank you very much! I hope you have a very nice evening just like mine right now :)))

Comment: is there any reason why this JS works great when clicking on 1 modal but when clicking on the second modal it won't work? What do you think it could cause this?

Comment: @xake If you mean you have 2, or more, such modal elements, then yes. The above code  sample only finds the first. To find more than 1 you need to use e.g. `querySelectorAll()` and then loop through the result attaching a listener on each.

Comment: Hmm, how do i create the loop ? Wouldn't it work if i have the same classes for all the modules i have as i have around 10 @LGSon

Comment: @xake Added a 3rd sample to give you a hint on how to do